# Expand RAID10 storage on Perc H730?

Tags: command-line, raid, hyper-v

I have a server I built, and one of the components is a Dell PERC H730 raid controller.  I have an 8 disk RAID10 array, and I'd like to replace the disks one by one and then expand the array.  The old disks are 3TB and the new ones are 16TB.  I'd like to keep the server online as I do this as well.  My challenge is that the server is HyperV 2016 server, so I'm limited to the perccli command line app, and I'm having a hard time figuring out the commands I need.  I think in the GUI I would use "Replace member" but I can't seem to find that in the command line help.

What commands do I need to issue before I take a drive out, and what would I need to put the new disk into service in the array?  Also how to monitor the rebuild status and then finally expand the RAID10 to fill the new space.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you considered using the iDrac? It’ll give you a GUI to manage this possibly.

Comment: @Appleoddity Possibly, but I'm not at all familiar with that either.  I've been trying to install Open Manage, but for some reason the installation ends up incomplete (only installs the web UI, none of the other required services).

Comment: I vaguely remember the open manage stuff. That’s not needed for iDrac. If the server has iDrac and it’s enabled, you simply connect to the iDrac’s IP address with a web browser and login. It’s not software installed on your server. It’s software running at the firmware level on the motherboard and runs independently of the operating system. The server doesn’t even have to be powered on to access it. Unfortunately, if you’re unaware of it it’s probably not configured. It would require at least rebooting the server in to the system settings to configure it initially.

Comment: @Appleoddity Right, but I don't have an idrac, so I was hoping to get a gui with open manage :-)